# Finding dy/dx as a function of x for a dog-walker dragged by a dog travelling in a straight line

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, problem-solving

**Hello.
I was wondering if anyone could provide some insight into how to solve the following Calculus word problem:**

Max is walking his dog Beau in the Cartesian plane, with the leash between them at its full
10 ft extension.

They walk up the negative y-axis, but just as Beau reaches the origin
he spots a squirrel and starts running along the line *y* = *x* (in the positive direction),
dragging Max behind him. The leash stays at full extension throughout and at any given
instant is tangent to the curve Max is dragged along.

[image: Beau pulling Max along the Cartesian plane]

If (*x, y*) is a point on the curve Max is dragged along, find *dy/dx* as a function of *x*.

Hint: If Beau is at (*u, u*) when Max is at (*x, y*), then the slope of the line joining them
and the distance between them, respectively, are?

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Useful keyword: [Tractrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix)

Comment: What are your thoughts on the hint given with the problem?

Comment: You have to assume the leash was taught when Beau spotted the squirrel.  That gives you Max's position when Max takes off on the line $y=x$

Comment: Tractrix is an interesting concept, but we have not covered it in class. There is likely a more streamlined way to solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation of the trajectory is $$y'=\frac {y-u}{x-u}$$with $u$ obtained solving$$(x-u)^2+(y-u)^2=100$$and choosing the root with the plus sign.

The initial condition is $\,y(0)=-10\,$ of course.

Comment: So lets say I wanted to locates Max's position when Beau is at (6,6) on the Cartesian plane. How would I use that point in the equation?

Comment: The point is that the ode can be solved only numerically. The first thing I have in mind is a pedestrian strategy: to plot $\{(x_i,(x_i-6)^2+(y_i-6)^2-100)\}$ where$\{(x_i,y_i)\}$ is a table of values of the solution and compare with x-axis.